# Execute link_tag from own html_helper

Tags: codeigniter

I want to execute the standard `link_tag();` but from within my own MY_html_helper.php in /application/helpers I can't execute the normal way:

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$link = $CI->html->link_tags($href);
```

I doesn't work within this helper...

Answer (score 2):

Each helper file is simply a collection of functions and to use those you need to load it first and in your case you want to use it from your own helper file so you need to load the helper file using codeIgniter's load method and to do it you should

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->load->helper('html');
echo link_tags($href);
```

Comment: _return_ and _echo_ return nothing. In another own helper I've used return and it works perfect...

Comment: How did you use your `link_tag_cachebusting` function and is your `MY_html_helper.php` is loaded ?

Comment: You should use it as `echo link_tag_cachebusting('link_here')`

Comment: Using echo instead of return doesn't change anything... Isn't it better to use return in a helper function anyway?